# Does anyone know this format of XML serialization Key=Value?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

From the source of HTML page I'm able to retrieve traces in the next format:

```
{LIST_EXCLUDED=[],LIST_TEST={HIGHLIGHTING_COLOR=#000000,TEST_HIERARCHY=5,COLOR=#E7E7B5,TEST_NAME=TEST,SHORT_NAME=TEST,COLOR_NAME=CUSTOM},TEST_BOUND=[{LIST_TESTS=[{LSA_DEBUG_INFO={FIRST_TEST_NUMBER=3,RBD=T},TEST_ID=0,NUMBER_OF_LAST_ACTIONS=9}]}],TEST_REC_ID=171}
```

It looks pretty like JSON format but a bit different.
I need to parse this value and to search it for the values that are needed. Does anyone know if it's a kind of standard structure or specific parses need to be written in this case?

Comment: I think it might be TCL.

Comment: @Bathsheba, doesn't look like :(

Comment: Well, it isn't any kind of XML, for a start.

Comment: @IanMcLaird, why? Can't we make an XML from it? E.g.:
    <LIST_EXCLUDED />
    <LIST_TEST>
           <HIGHLIGHTING_COLOR>#000000</HIGHLIGHTING_COLOR>
           <TEST_HIERARCHY> ...
...
From my point of view it's possible to make XML from this "serialized" data.

Comment: Without knowing the format, we can't know that for certain.  XML requires a single root node, which we don't know if this format has or requires.  Further, the ability to turn something *into* XML doesn't make that thing XML.  You can often translate JSON into XML.  XML and JSON are nevertheless two completely different formats.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @IanMcLaird. It's not very important for the solution if it's XML or not. To be honest, I know for sure that originally it was an XML (insights ;)). But still somehow I need to parse this to something to be able to search it and navigate over "nodes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I didn't get any answer about standard libraries that can be used in this case I had to convert this data into JSON.
I've used next replaces:

```
// key=value
parsedDataMap = parsedDataMap.replaceAll("([,\\{\\[]{1})([^,\\{\\[=]+)=([^,\\{\\}\\[\\]]+)([,\\}\\]]{1})",
    "$1\"$2\":\"$3\"$4");
// key=value 2nd time because some of the values were missed 1st time because of intersection of ranges
parsedDataMap = parsedDataMap.replaceAll("([,\\{\\[]{1})([^\",\\{\\[=]+)=([^\",\\{\\}\\[\\]]+)([,\\}\\]]{1})",
    "$1\"$2\":\"$3\"$4");
// key=[ or key={
parsedDataMap = parsedDataMap.replaceAll("([,\\{\\[]{1})([^,\\{\\[=]+)=([\\[\\{])", "$1\"$2\":$3");
// key=[ or key={ 2nd time because some of the values were missed 1st time because of intersection of ranges
parsedDataMap = parsedDataMap.replaceAll("([,\\{\\[]{1})([^\",\\{\\[=]+)=([\\[\\{])", "$1\"$2\":$3");
```

Answer (score -1):

if there is no '=' inside strings, then replace '=' with ':' and do as you do with json

Comment: Nope, Json uses `"` to surround the keys and the values: `"key" : "value"`